# When is File.join useful?

Tags: ruby

From reading the documentation, it's apparent that File.join joins the given parameters with the / character.
When is using this, as opposed to `filenames.join('/')`, beneficial?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

There is another, subtle difference:

```
File.join('foo','bar')
#=> "foo/bar"
['foo','bar'].join('/')
#=> "foo/bar"
```

But, if you pass an argument already ending with `/` (which is quite often when working with paths), you won't have two slashes in the result:

```
File.join('foo/','bar')
#=> "foo/bar"
['foo/','bar'].join('/')
#=> "foo//bar"
```

Comment: Is there a bug in SO or I have really been upvoted 5 times in 3 minutes?!

Comment: Sometimes what you think are your most trivial answers get the most upvotes. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793693/why-would-yaml-be-unavailable-in-production/1793719#1793719) is one of my most upvoted answers.

Comment: 12 years later I am upvoting because I've been writing the literal code to do this for what seems like forever. I imagine a few people landed here with a similar experience!

Answer (score 19):

It will use `File::SEPARATOR`, which in theory need not be `/`.

Comment: Actually, it uses `/` on Windows as well. Because `File::SEPARATOR` is "/" on Windows - only `File::ALT_SEPARATOR` is "\\".

Comment: Thanks, @sepp2k.  Maybe you should add an answer if you know why they chose that design.

Comment: Are there any platforms Ruby runs on where / is not a valid file separator?

Comment: @fahadsadah: I'm not sure, but you may want to look at [Ruby 1.9 Drops Support For 9 Platforms (Ruby 1.9.0-3′s Release Bombshell)](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-1-9-0-3-and-drops-support-for-9-platforms-970.html)