# Compiling Ruby 1.9.2 under Linux (Ubuntu) and Rubygems

Tags: ruby, compilation, rubygems

I already installed Ruby 1.9.2 with Rubygems successfully on my main machine.

Now on my server I'm again in this job.

Last time I had a problem, which came up right now as well:

```
gem install rails
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    no such file to load -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

I knew how to fix this, but forgot it.

I found an article here on stackoverflow (which I cannot find again) that tells me to compile some native ruby extension first. In the source code you have to go into a dir, where you find dirs for zlib, linecache and so on. Those you have to compile and you're done: everything then works.

Can somebody tell me again how to do this?

Sorry, Google and the Stackoverflow search didn't help this time.

Thanks.

Yours,

Joern

Comment: Did you install `zlib1g-dev` before compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the thread again!

[Has anyone tried installing ruby & rubygems from source on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250329/has-anyone-tried-installing-ruby-rubygems-from-source-on-ubuntu-preferably-unb)

In the 3rd answer of Evgeny you find exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 1):

1. use RVM to install a ruby - its really incredible stuff
2. you didnt used flags on the ruby compilation (--with-zlib-dir=/...zlib_path...)

Comment: no, last time it was different, without any flags - and no I won't use RVM, for that I think it's a piece of crap

Comment: on your system must be installed a zlib package and at a compilation you must use flags, I'm confident this