# Properly installing Ruby enviroment for Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I know there are a lot of questions around for this issue. Already came across different fixes I've read about but I simply can't get gem to work properly, I always end up having the output:

> ```
> ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
>   cannot load such file -- zlib
> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
>     undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
> ```

For any gem I try to install. I first had ruby installed from the repository packages, then I installed *all*, including rails from https://rvm.io/ by performing `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

I already did `sudo apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libreadline-dev libssl-dev`
 and so `rvm remove 2.1.0p0`, `rvm remove 2.1.0` and `rvm reinstall 2..1.0` as `ruby -v` outputs 2.1.0p0

I simply want to get my ruby enviroment working. What's a stable fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did follow what this [answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250329/has-anyone-tried-installing-ruby-rubygems-from-source-on-ubuntu-preferably-un/7126813#7126813).

I had already installed the mentioned packages first so I didn't have to *re* `make` anything.

It worked like charm, hope it helps in future.